# 14.04 to 16.04 upgrade : Huge slowdown, why?

Tags: 16.04, 64-bit, kde, performance, 32-bit

I have an older laptop with 2GB RAM. I have been running Kubuntu 32-bit installations for a number of years. I decided to move from 14.04 to 16.04. I had the option of 32-bit or 64-bit. I do have the requisite 2GB, so I decided to upgrade to 64-bit. I do not know if it is the 64-bit upgrade that is using up all my available RAM and some of my swap on startup, or if the new KDE is that much more of a system hog. But anything I do measures time in fractions of minutes rather than in seconds.

Barring adding 2GB more to my system, would I be better off to drop back to 32-bit? Or should I check KDE? I have built my entire system around the KDE utilities - but I will switch if that is the most likely culprit.

Any ideas or suggestions?

**free -h**:

```
     total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:  2.0G        799M         52M        113M        1.1G        1.0G
Swap: 2.0G        733M        1.3G
```

Comment: add more details, please:  GPU/CPU/ `cat /etc/default/grub` result

Comment: **CPU:** Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     T7300  @ 2.00GHz
**GPU:** Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller

**The only things uncommented in /etc/default/grub:**
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

Comment: my `free -h` output.  `Swap:         total:  3.2G         used: 0B        free: 3.2G` , if there's heavy swap usage, you have not enough memory. If it's not the case, you should check if your current video drivers support hardware rendering

Comment: According to glxinfo, direct rendering is enabled. Is that what you mean?

Comment: yes. idk then. if you checked memory... maybe evolution/zeitgeist/chrome eat too many resources?

Comment: Thanks for your comments and time. I have reduced the memory load from the plasmashell, and performance, while still slow, is almost acceptable, so I'm still trying to decide whether to bear with the current status until such a time that I can get more memory, or whether to dump the installation and begin again with 32-bit.

Comment: you can switch to lubuntu, it eats much less memory